# Android BottomSheetBehavior takes all height in viewpager2 even it is collapsed

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager2

I have a thin bottom info fragment over a map what can be clicked and it expands with more info (bottomsheetbehaviour). This works fine alone and the map can be panned after the bottomsheet is collapsed back. The problem is when I try to put the bottom fragment into viewpager2. It works fine but it will take all the expanded height even it is collapsed and the map cannot be panned or clicked within that area. Viewpager height is wrap_content. Any ideas how this could be fixed so that viewpager height would change when height of the fragment inside viepager changes?

I've tried different methods and always it takes the same height. This works fine without viewpager with only one fragment but I need viewpager.

This can be reproduced with a simple test app

activity_main.xml

```
   <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

MainActivity

```
 mViewPager = findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), getLifecycle());
    mAdapter.addFragment(new BottomInfoFragment());
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "CLICK!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

This does not work. When floating action button is pressed nothing happens, Toast is not shown.

[image]

---

But if only fragment is added it works

activity_main.xml

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/bottom_info_view"
    android:name="com.example.myapplication.BottomInfoFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/constraintLayout"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="center"
    tools:layout="@layout/bottom_info_fragment" />

<!--<androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />-->
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

MainActivity

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    /*mViewPager = findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), getLifecycle());
    mAdapter.addFragment(new BottomInfoFragment());
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);*/
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "CLICK!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

bottom_info_fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent">

<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="65dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="@color/black"
    app:layout_behavior=
    "com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/teal_200"
        android:orientation="vertical" />
</RelativeLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

When pressed floating action button Toast is shown.
[image]

And in both cases bottomsheet works as should it can be slided up over the button.

[image]

Does anyone know how I can add a viewpager with fragments that have bottomsheetbehaviour and that the under layer is responsive also when bottomsheet is collapsed?

Comment: Add a [mcve] with question .